# Переход по элементу ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Есть ListView:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Some}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSome}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=StartTime}" FontSize="16"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public SomeViewModel SelectedSome
            {
                get => _selectedSome;
                set
                {
                    SetProperty(ref _selectedSome, value);
                    var navigationParam = new NavigationParameters {{"key", value.Some}};
                    _regionManager.RequestNavigate("1", "2",
                        navigationParam);
                }
            }
```

При первом переходе на один из элементов ListView переход осуществляется. Выхожу с View обратно к выбору в ListView. Повторно нажимаю на тот же элемент ListView, ничего не происходит. Жму Ctrl + ЛКМ, value в свойстве SelectedSome равно null, F5, опять кликаю по тому же элементу, переходит. Почему с первого раза не переходит? И что дает Ctrl + ЛКМ? 
UPDATE: Скорее всего мне нужно обнулять SelectedSome, только как его обнулять

Answer (score 0):

Надо было обнулять свойство, а так же к биндингу этого же свойства добавить `Mode=TwoWay`